# Proof of relationship between nodes (n) and height (h) of Full Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree, proof

I have an assignment that reads as follows

> Prove that the relationship between nodes (n) and height (h) of Full Binary Tree
>   is 2^h=(n+1)/2.

I have tried the following:

n = 2^(h+1)-1

n+1 = 2^(h+1)

n+1 = 2^h*2

therefore

2^h=(n+1)/2

I know this cant be that simple. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

From where did you get n = 2^(h+1)-1 ? If you take that formula for granted, there's not much left to prove!

This is type of exercise is typically solved by induction. Here are the steps:

- Show that it holds for the base case, h = 0. Usually completely trivial.
- Assume that it holds for a fixed height, i.e. that the formula holds for h = k
- Show (under the above assumption) that it holds for h = k+1.